# Detect keyboard input after windows recognition of the key

Tags: c++, windows, button, input, keyboard-input

I am building a program that would print out the pressed buttons' values on the screen. I need it to work also when the program's window is not active. I tried using GetAsyncKeyState(int), which works fine. However, I can attach certain strings to keys, but it doesn't work for all types of keyboards (for example, on english keyboards shift+2 is @, while on mine its not). How can I detect post-processing of the key input that is done by Windows (the character that is printed on the screen when writing in Notepad)?

Comment: You probably want to set a windows keyboard hook.

Comment: Why does your program need to do this? Is it an IME? An on-screen keyboard? A keylogger? There are special interfaces for IME to do this. On-screen keyboards typically don't show the resulting key (it shows up in the target app).

Comment: Jerry Coffin > Thanks for your suggestion. Seems like it would work, however, it doesn't seem very easy to implement. Any examples of code?

Comment: Raymond Chen > It's supposed to be a game played together with a friend on one keyboard, where they need to find certain keys as fast as possible.

Comment: Then have the game tell you when it got the character and what character it is.

Comment: Virtual keys need to be translated to typing keys according to the active keyboard layout and the current keyboard state.  A Windows program leaves that up to Windows.  It calls TranslateMessage() inside the message loop and listens for the WM_CHAR messages.  It isn't clear why you'd want to do this differently, using GetAsyncKeyState() is certainly the worst possible way to do it.  Best not to.

Comment: Raymond Chen > Yes, but the problem is that I want it to be usable on different computers with different keyboards. If I would program it the way I program it now, it will only work on the keyboard that I am using.

Comment: Hans Passant > I understand that this way is not a good choice. I never listened for keyboard inputs in such way, so don't know how coders approach it. Can you elaborate on TranslateMessage() method and WM_CHAR? I read Microsoft's page, but it's extremely hard to understand how it's used. Maybe an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the OemKeyScan function.  With yours you should have the [scancode](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/m24kbd.png) (e.g. the "2" key has a given scancode that is always the same depending on position on the keyboard, e.g 17 for the "2" key):

```
    int whichscancode= 17;
    if (key_with_shift)
        whichscancode|= (1<<16);  // shifted values with 1<<16

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
            int scan= ::OemKeyScan(i);  // try all characters for a matching scancode
            if (scan==whichscancode) {
                // i here is the ascii code of the key on that position
                printf("on that scancode is character %c\n", (char)i);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I get the scancode that is the same on all keyboards. It works, but how can I use it together with GetAsyncKeyState(int), which takes a virtual key as input? I want that on any keyboard if I write symbol "@", no matter whether it's shift+2 or shift+', it would give me "@".